# freemarker , ways to update hasmap

Tags: hashmap, immutability, freemarker

I started working on ftl [freemarker](http://freemarker.org) recently. 
I created a hasmap using the #assign .

What is the recommended way to update the values of this hashMap ?

Are the datastructures(map , list etc) immutable in freemarker ?

```
<#assign hashMap1= { "name": "mouse", "price": 50 } >
hashMap1.name = "cat";  // gives error
<#assign hashMap1= hashMap1 + {"name": "cat"} /> // this works fine , but I don't like this approach. it gives false sense of adding keys where we are updating keys.
```

I tried going through here [freemarker builtins](http://freemarker.org) , but there is no information on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FTL actually doesn't support modifying data structures. (It's not a generic script language, just a template language.) With `hashMap1 = hashMap1 + {"name": "cat"}` you aren't updating the existing hash, you are creating a new hash which contains the new key. For that  reason I also wouldn't recommend doing it for too many times, as it will get slow (especially the resulting hash).

If you really need to update `Map`-s from templates, you have to give the template a real Java `Map`, and use `?api` to access Java's `Map` API.

Comment: adding the reference given by you in other answer.
http://freemarker.org/docs/app_faq.html#faq_modify_seq_and_map